# Lost seed phrase. How to recover it back?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, cryptocurrency

Is there a way I can recover my metamask seed phrase through IP Address? I accidentally logged out and I have not saved the phrase. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you did not save your seed phrase you must log in to Metamask and go to the advanced options to retrieve it. There is no other way.